# How to exclude document fields while importing from Mongo DB to target systems like ElasticSearch/Solr using Mongo-Connector?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, solr, connector

**Mongo DB** provides a **connector** to integrate the data from **Mongo database** to **targets** like **Solr**, **ElasticSearch**. I am using this connector to move data from **Mongo Collection** from a particular database to **ElasticSearch index**.

How can I **exclude** the **specified fields** while loading data from **Mongo database** to **index in ElasticSearch**?.

Comment: This question talks about exclude fields where as referenced question talks about include fields and mapping. I found very difficult to figure out the solution for excluding fields. So to help others I created this question specially on excluding fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Mongo-Connector** https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector is a perfect solution to move the data from Mongo Databases to target systems like **Solr, ElasticSearch,** etc...

This **connector** offers several options which are used to exclude fields, exclude collections, exclude namespaces i.e., databases, include fields, mapping to destination namespaces i.e., index names in ElasticSearch, etc...

> To Exclude fields, run the mongo-connector as follows:

```
mongo-connector -t http://localhost:9200 -m localhost:27017 -d elastic2_doc_manager -e city,name -n <database_name>.<collection_name>
```

> Mongo-connector also supports excluding nested fields. Use the
>   following notation to exclude the nested fields:

```
mongo-connector -t http://localhost:9200 -m localhost:27017 -d elastic2_doc_manager -e address.city,address.geopoint.lat -n <database_name>.<collection_name>
```

**Note:** we cannot use both include_fields and exclude_fields with connector because they are mutually exclusive.
Do not prefix the database name and collection name for the exclude fields.

Comment: Was the whole point of this to be a self answer? Can you please not type everything in bold? It's very disconcerting and feels like someone is poking me in the forehead.

Comment: Sorry for that, I posted this question to help others. The mongo-connector documentation is not provided examples to exclude the fields.

Comment: Maybe not. But there are also other answers here already for both elastic search and solr.